# Spring or Spring Boot integration with legacy codebase

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot

given an existing, non-Spring based code, is it possible to wire together dependencies using Spring without changing how the other parts of the code work? In particular, most Spring/Boot examples call SpringApplication.run in the main, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
}
```

I can't do this, I just want Spring Boot to wire dependencies when a certain method (getter) is called. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need Spring Boot to wire dependencies, if you have a lot of legacy xml-d code you can continue to define beans there and autowire it with spring's `@Autowired` annotation

Comment: I want to create a library that does not depend on whether the the app that uses it is Spring-based or not. So xml is not an option.

Comment: Spring allows you to autowire beans which were defined in xml or via annotations.. So if you want to use spring's autowiring then you need to use that framework.. Otherwise you can use JEE.. Or I understood you wrong?

Comment: If you're creating a library you should not depend on Spring Framework at all as it will force its clients to use Spring too. If you design your components correctly Spring will have no problems using and configuring them.